# Error 419 peticion POST con csrf en laravel 8 y login con livewire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

Tengo una aplicacion en en heroku que al intentar registrar al usuario me bota el error 419 y revisando, si esta el csrf, tambien cambie el appkey de la aplicacion y borre cache y sesion, revisando me di cuenta que la ruta de mi formulario la esta colocando en HTTP y no HTTPS siendo que asi esta la url web saben porque puede ser?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: agrega código no imagen

Comment: Bienvenido, revisar [ask] saudos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despues de todo encontre la respuesta a mi problema, todo se solucionaba forzando las urls a HTTPS con una linea en el Appservice provider, abajo dejo el codigo de mi Appservice provider

```
`<?php
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
  
    public function register()
    {
      
    }

  
    public function boot()
    {
        resolve(\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::class)-**texto en negrita**>forceScheme('https');
    }
}`
```